# Gem: wicked_pdf - Couldn't find Post without an ID (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Couldn't find Post without an ID

My routes:

```
get '/download_pdf(.:format)' => 'posts#show', :method => :get, :as=>:show
```

My link to create PDF on the show page:

```
<%= link_to "Create PDF document", show_path(@post, :format => :pdf) %>
```

My show action:

```
def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "show",:layout => 'pdf.html.erb',:template => '/post/show' 
      end
    end
  end
```

I have show.pdf.erb

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params[:id]` is empty in your show action. It's probably better to do this with resources in your routes.rb file and create a route that looks like:

```
get '/download_pdf/:id(.:format)'
```

Hope this helps you get in the right direction.